# How can I change Eclipse theme?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes

I want to change Eclipse theme like this Eclipse Dark Theme:

[image: eclipse dark theme]

I try to do all step in this page but eclipse theme not changed (but eclipse editor changed).
I want to change all part of eclipse IDE change to black color, not only eclipse's editor.

Comment: What do you mean with "eclipse editor changed"? Please add a lot of additional information to your question. Without some explanation or images, it's really hard to help.

Answer (score 137):

Take a look at [rogerdudler/eclipse-ui-themes](https://github.com/rogerdudler/eclipse-ui-themes) . In the readme there is a link to a file that you need to extract into your `eclipse/dropins` folder.

When you have done that go to

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance

And change the theme from GTK (or what ever it is currently) to `Dark Juno` (or Dark).

That will change the UI to a nice dark theme but to get the complete look and feel you can get the Eclipse Color Theme plugin from eclipsecolorthemes.org. The easiest way is to add this update URI to "Help -> Install New Software" and install it from there.

[Eclipse Color Themes](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/)

This adds a "Color Theme" menu item under

> Window -> Preferences -> Appearance

Where you can select from a large range of editor themes. My preferred one to use with PyDev is Wombat. For Java `Solarized Dark`

Comment: eclipse-color-theme doesn't work for me. I use MacOS Mountain Lion. It's adds nothing to Appearance themes.

Comment: it's there on Mac 10.9, but it seems only to affect the one source-code window pane.  All the other panes are still crystal-meth white.  Better to just use Ctrl-Fan-Alt-8 and reverse-video the whole machine.

Comment: Its not working with eclipse indigo in window 8 64bit OS

Comment: mnn : Themes are only working with versions after indigo. Such as juno and kelper.

Comment: Choosing dark theme changes everything except the editor color theme. Why?

Comment: You need Eclipse Color Themes installed to change the colour inside an editor window

Comment: Its not working on any Eclipse on MacOS i had tried, I keep getting angry, that even the simplest thing is not able in this ... editor...

Comment: zip file in the github link works no more

Answer (score 19):

Update December 2012 (19 months later):

The blog post "[Jin Mingjian: Eclipse Darker Theme](http://jmj-eclipse.blogspot.com/2012/12/eclipse-darker-theme-and-sorry-to.html)" mentions this [GitHub repo "**eclipse themes - darker**"](https://github.com/jinmingjian/eclipse.themes.darker):

[image]

> The big fun is that, the codes are minimized by using Eclipse4 platform technologies like **[dependency injection](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection)**.
>   It proves that again, the concise codes and advanced features could be achieved by contributing or extending with the external form (like library, framework).
>   New language is not necessary just for this kind of purpose.

---

Update July 2012 (14 months later):

With the latest Eclipse4.2 (June 2012, "Juno") release, you can implement what I originally described below: a CSS-based fully dark theme for Eclipse.
See the article by [Lars Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548637/vogella) in "[Eclipse 4 is beautiful – Create your own Eclipse 4 theme](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/07/11/eclipse-4-is-beautiful-create-your-own-eclipse-4-theme/)":

[image: Eclipse fully dark theme]

> If you want to play with it, you only need to write a plug-in, create a CSS file and use the **`org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme`** extension point to point to your file.
>   If you export your plug-in, place it in the “dropins” folder of your Eclipse installation and your styling is available.

---

Original answer: August 2011

With Eclipse 3.x, theme is only for the editors, as you can see in the site "[Eclipse Color Themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/)".
Anything around that is managed by windows system colors.
That is what you need to change to have any influence on Eclipse global colors *around* editors.

Eclipse 4 will provide much advance theme options: See "[Eclipse 4.0 – So you can theme me Part 1](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2010/08/05/eclipse-4-0-so-you-can-theme-me-part-1/)" and "[Eclipse 4.0 RCP: Dynamic CSS Theme Switching](http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=113)".

[image: dark theme]

Answer (score 17):

[image]
My Theme plugin provide full featured customization for Eclipse 4.
Try it.
[Visit Plugin Page](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I want! Clean, compact and sleek. I can not ask for more. Bless you.

Comment: this would be almost great if you could change background of project explorer window and two columns surrounding a column where number of line in code is written.

Answer (score 17):

The best way to Install new themes in any Eclipse platform is to use the Eclipse Marketplace.

1.Go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace

2.Search for "Color Themes"

3.Install and Restart

4.Go to Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Color Themes

5.Select anyone and Apply. Restart.

Answer (score 4):

In the eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) on windows
Go to Window > preferences > Appearance
Select the required theme for dark theme to choose **Dark** and click on Ok.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Eclipse...]
To just get everything done goto 
Window>Preferences>General and goto theme menu and change it...
Then re-start to apply...