# Unable to fully change Eclipse ADT theme color scheme

Tags: java, android, eclipse, themes, adt

I am trying to change my ADT (Eclipse) IDE color scheme to a dark one.
As instructed on many threads (for example [How can I change Eclipse theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937825/how-can-i-change-eclipse-theme)) -

1. I've installed DARK JUNO (as instructed on the link)
2. I've installed Eclipse Color Theme plugin from eclipsecolorthemes.org (as instructed on the link)

And still, the results are partly dark, partly light color scheme with strage font sizes and very strange (and ugly look).

If I only use Eclipse Color Theme plugin, without choosing the DARK JUNO theme, only the compiler (center "code area") receives the right look.

This is how my IDE looks right now (with JUNO on and a color scheme from Eclipse Color Theme plugin) - http://tinyurl.com/o5bdl4e.
I've marked a few annoying parts.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[did you reffer this ?](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=how-to-use) 
anyway ,
I suggest you to try change eclipse -- preferences > general > appearance > colors and fonts > in hre change Dialog Font. this will change views font.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the moonrise theme. It should work similar to dark juno, but it looks much nicer and allow you to use the color theme pack for text.