# Eclipse Kepler window drawing problems in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

Eclipse `Juno` (from the Ubuntu repo) (3.8.1) looks fine:

[image]

Eclipse `Kepler` (download from Eclipse website) looks broken:

[image]

How do I fix my Window drawing for `Kepler` (and preferably make it look as compact as `Juno`)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the appearance in `Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance`.

Restart eclipse.

You can also use [colour theme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) plug-in. It only changes the text in editors i.e syntax highlighter.

#### Edit

Look at these links for new themes.

[How can I change Eclipse theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937825/how-can-i-change-eclipse-theme)

[Creating eclipse themes](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2010/08/05/eclipse-4-0-so-you-can-theme-me-part-1/)

[eclipse-themes](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes)