# The look of eclipse changed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've got a question it's not code related, it's eclipse rated. So i installed the mcp (Minecraft Coder Pack) because if felt like modding the game, and to do so you need to change your java work-space, in doing so the look of eclipse changed.

[image: Original]

That's what my eclipse usually looks like but when i opened up the new one it looked like this.

[image: New]

My question is is there a way to fix it? I prefer the look of the original eclipse and the blocky one is just distracting. And doesn't look as cool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i change Eclipse theme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937825/how-can-i-change-eclipse-theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your General > Appearence > Theme

Comment: There's no theme? Nvm, found it.

Comment: Try setting it to Windows 7